# (List<Dictionary<Object, Object>> in Linq to extract data

Tags: c#, linq

I have a data definition

I  Deserialize JSON to this object

@return is JSON

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Dictionary<Object, Object>>>(utils.RemoveJsonOuterClass("GetTable", JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(@return).ToString()));

olist = [
    [{
        "item": 1
        "Name "One"
    }],
    [{
        "item": 2
        "Name "Two"
    }],
    [{
        "item": 1
        "Name "One Two"
    }]
];
```

This is a `List<Dictionary<Object, Object>>`

I need to find all of the items where `"item" == 1`.

Can I Use Linq? or is there any other way while using a large amount of data?

Comment: can you provide the code that populates your list? since I don't see a dictionary of {object, object}

Comment: I see Array<Array<Object>> ?

Answer (score 0):

**First:** Your `json` is not correct fix that.

- A `colon` should be present between Name and value.
- A `comma` should be present after item value

and then change your code as below

```
//Create a class matching response object
public class ResponseItem
{
    [JsonProperty("item")]
    public int Item { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

var responseJson = utils.RemoveJsonOuterClass("GetTable", 
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(@return).ToString();

var responseData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<ResponseItem, ResponseItem>>>(responseJson);
```

Then use `foreach` with `Where` and apply condition

```
foreach (var responseObject in responseData.Where(x=>x.First().Item.Equals(1)))
{

}
```

`Where` is deferred execution and on each loop, it returns an object.
 Here is the screenshot of my local execution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if u're right with the object type. But the task is easy to solve:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Build the object
    List<Dictionary<int, TestObject>> list = new List<Dictionary<int, TestObject>>();

    // fill it with dictionaries
    list.Add(new List<TestObject>()
    {
        new TestObject(){ Id = 1, Name = "One" },
        new TestObject() { Id = 2, Name = "Two" },
        new TestObject() { Id = 3, Name = "Three" }
    }.ToDictionary(d => d.Id));

    list.Add(new List<TestObject>()
    {
        new TestObject() { Id = 2, Name = "Two" },
        new TestObject() { Id = 3, Name = "Three" }
    }.ToDictionary(d => d.Id));

    list.Add(new List<TestObject>()
    {
        new TestObject(){ Id = 1, Name = "One" },
        new TestObject() { Id = 2, Name = "Two" }
    }.ToDictionary(d => d.Id));

    // Let's build a single list to work with
    IEnumerable<TestObject> completeList = list.SelectMany(s => s.Values);

    // aaaand filter it
    IEnumerable<TestObject> filteredList = completeList.Where(l => l.Id == 1);
}

public class TestObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Most part is initialization ;-)